# Local Database Is Not Connecting in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, networking, service, local-database

I newly installed SQL server 2012 .when install my Database their is a local server .then i created a db in local server about my new project.my system is in a network i install with admin permition. my db name is E4events and there are many tables in it.am also accessing network server db also from my sql server.i worked in local server db for 2 days on third day it is not connecting i refer and try to clear problem by many reference but still i cant connect .I am not feared about connection .i created lot of tables so if i can connect i will get data or otherwise please suggest me how to get that db and whole tables.  so here below i attached meathods i tried to solve problem but i dint become succes

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Check Windows Event log. It may have some useful details regarding why you can't start SQL Server. (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools->Event Viewer)

Comment: i want to get my data for that i need to connect to database.plz hlp me

Comment: Until you check Event Log and post more details, we can't help.

Comment: In event log what all details u need?

Comment: check "Application" and "Sytem" collections. Look for events related to your SQL Service starting. (Note: it may help if you try to start you SQL Server just before you do the log checking so that events appear at the top (or close to the top)